# How to access data on XP from ubuntu 10.04 inside VMPlayer?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, vmware-player

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to do networking between virtual machines in VirtualBox?](https://superuser.com/questions/119732/how-to-do-networking-between-virtual-machines-in-virtualbox)

My OS is windows XP and I run ubuntu 10.04 through VMPlayer.

Is there a way that these two OSs can share a folder so that I can copy files between them?