# Setting up Metasploiable 2 network

Tags: networking, virtualbox, kali-linux

I've recently installed `Metasploitable 2` and I would like to set up it's network in the following way:
I'm running `Metasploitable 2` on a `VirtualBox` on my PC, and what I'd like to do is to be able to communicate with it through `Kali Linux` which is installed on my laptop (not virtually).

My question is: How do I need to set up the network on `VirtualBox` for this to work?

I already tried: [How to do networking between virtual machines in VirtualBox?](https://superuser.com/questions/119732/how-to-do-networking-between-virtual-machines-in-virtualbox) 
with no success, probably because I only have one VM and can't choose `Internal Network` because `Metasploitable 2` is full of exploits which will expose me to hackers...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might I suggest Vagrant? You may find it's substantially simpler to stand up multiple boxes for attack / defense by familiarising yourself with both hardening techniques in Metasploitable and attack techniques in Kali. Added bonus, when you're done for the day you can blow away the boxes with a quick `vagrant destroy` and start over the next day with `vagrant up` from scratch. You can also `vagrant destroy` at the end of your sessions to ensure you don't leave metasploitable running.
A candidate vagrantfile is here: https://github.com/madsec/tha-lab_setup/blob/master/assets/Vagrantfile

Comment: Metasploitable 2 is full of exploits for others. All though I can understand that it might have its own security flaws, I am 100% sure a hacker is not going to be waiting for you specifically to turn it on. If you really think that a hacker will pwn your box instantly then your ego must be very large ;P.

Comment: @Tealkine Thanks for the reply. I thought about it as well, and your probably right. The reason I was asking is because I saw some tutorials and guides for setting up `Metasploitable 2` and each of them recommended for setting it up with `Host-only Adapter`...