# Linux Windows virtual box guests communicating

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I have a Windows 7 Host with two Virtual boxes configured for:

1. Windows 7 Guest
2. Linux Guest

I am trying to use the host-only and internal network options, and I see various others options mentioned here and that's not working for me.

1. I have setup the NAT to access the Internet for both the guests
2. Host only network with static IP assigned for each of the guests
3. I have the third network card / adapter  for the internal networking

Having said this, and explained my setup above, I have the following results:

1. The host is able to network with both the guests
2. Windows guest to host and the Linux guest is also fine
3. Linux to host is also fine, however Linux guest to Windows guest is not working

Now I need help as to where I am missing the steps for the Linux guest to not communicate to the Windows guest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do networking between virtual machines in VirtualBox?](http://superuser.com/questions/119732/how-to-do-networking-between-virtual-machines-in-virtualbox)

Comment: Well, l think that post is talking about the Bridged solution, however I am using a host-only network (to assign a unique IP to the interfaces which I can can use as a  as a a separate IP ) and then internal network for both my windows and Linux guests to talk to each other. 

Now I get the communication working from the windows guest to Linux guest working  but not the vice versa

Comment: Ho could some body be so mean of putting the question on hold even after telling that the Question is of a different scenario, and not let any body look at my Question no nor let any one answer it. every Question has its own scenario and has its own  possible solution. I never thought this forum so mean

Tell me how to mark it unanswered, I hope I have that liberty to mark it as unanswered?