# How to get two Debian VMs to communicate?

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, debian, virtual-machine

I'm trying to get two VMs with Pymodbus installed to communicate with each other, but I'm having a lot of difficulty with this. I'm very new to both networking and Linux, and most research that I've done on the topic hasn't gotten me very far because of my lack of experience. The basis for the project is to have these two virtual machines communicate with each other using the pymodbus functionality (https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus), and then have a third VM (running Kali) perform a DoS attack and a MitM attack on the Debian VMs in order to test and analyze SCADA security. I've been able to successfully install pymodbus on both VMs, but am having difficulty getting anything to work from there.

I've already looked at this thread ([How to do networking between virtual machines in VirtualBox?](https://superuser.com/questions/119732/how-to-do-networking-between-virtual-machines-in-virtualbox)), but cannot utilize Hyper-V because I'm running Win10 Home, so I cannot complete the tutorials there. This is honestly driving me crazy, and I've been trying for days to figure this out, but I really need some help. All VMs were created through VirtualBox. Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you follow that answer? First read about networking from VirtualBox manual given in VirtualBox installer.

Comment: what makes you think you need Hyper-V to do this?

Comment: How would you get two non-VMS to communicate?  Now replace and troubleshoot as needed.  There would be a NIC, a Switch, and IP addresses.  You have much the same it is just all virtual; but you technically trouble shoot it approximately the same.  Is the Virtual NIC working properly on the VM, Can you ping the internet or anything else?  Are they all in the same IP range?  are there any firewall rules hindering things?  Is Virtualbox "switching" hookedup properly; usually you would look at cabling, in Virtualbox it would be configuration based.

Comment: @FrankThomas The only reason I thought I needed Hyper-V was because the tutorials from the above post use it.

Comment: I'm not realling seeing anything about hyper-V on those links, but if you are using Virtualbox as your VM platform, then you need to create/configure your virtual network in Virtualbox. HyperV is a competing product from MS, so its one or the other. The accepted answer on your linked thread has the links you need to connect the VMs to a shared network. As for whether the virtual switches are vulnerable to whatever exploits you plan to use in your MITM, thats another story. you probably won't be able to use purely virtual assets to stage a realworld lab.